# MDX query issue on analysing data

Tags: mdx

I am working with "Adventure works" cube. I want to report Sales amount, Revenue goal for each fiscal year. I wrote below query but the answer is not what I expect.

```
Select{
(KPIValue("Operating Profit"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]), 
(KPIGoal("Operating Profit"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]),
(KPIStatus("Operating Profit"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]), 
(KPITrend("Operating Profit"), [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008])
} On COLUMNS,
DESCENDANTS
(
  {
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2006],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2007],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2008],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2009],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2011]
   }, [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year]
)On ROWS
From [Adventure Works]
```

How can I get the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you hardcode [Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2008]?
See [a documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/kpivalue-mdx). Try that:

```
Select{
KPIValue("Operating Profit"), 
KPIGoal("Operating Profit"),
KPIStatus("Operating Profit"), 
KPITrend("Operating Profit")
} On COLUMNS,
{
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2006],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2007],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2008],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2009],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2011]
} On ROWS
From [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: This query also is not giving the expected result.

Comment: How can I find sales amount?